# If $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$, what is $\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x-t)-f(x)|\, dx = ?$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Given $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$, compute the limit $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x-t)-f(x)|\, dx.$$

---

**My work.**
Of course, $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x-t)-f(x)|\, dx \le 2\|f\|_1 < \infty.$$
We know that step functions are dense in $L^1(\Bbb R)$. My first thought is to find an expression for $f = \mathbf{1}_{(a,b)}$, i.e., the indicator function of an interval. For simplicity, take $a = 0, b= 1$. Then,
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x-t)-f(x)|\, dx &= \int_0^1 1\, dx + \int_t^{t+1} 1\, dx = 2 = 2\|f\|_1 
\end{align*}$$
as $\|f\|_1 = 1$. It is easy to see that a similar equality holds for $f = \mathbf{1}_{(a,b)}$ in general.

1. If I can show that $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x-t)-f(x)|\, dx = 2\|f\|_1$$ for functions $f = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \mathbf{1}_{E_i}$ where $E_i$'s are disjoint intervals, then I can hope to use an approximation argument for the result.
2. Suppose the result holds for all step functions. Then, given $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$, there is a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ of step functions such that $\|f - f_n\|_1 \to 0$. We have $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f_n(x-t)-f_n(x)|\, dx = 2\|f_n\|_1$$ for every $n\ge 1$. Certainly, $\|f_n\|_1 \to \|f\|_1$ as $n\to \infty$. The hard part is showing that
   $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f_n(x-t)-f_n(x)|\, dx = \lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x-t)-f(x)|\, dx.$$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hint: It is easier to start from the fact that the set of all continuous functions (with compact supports) is dense in $L^1(\Bbb R)$. If you are not allowed to assume this fact, you can derive it from the fact that the set of step functions is dense.

Comment: Got it, thank you! @BigbearZzz

Comment: glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g_n\in\mathcal{C}_{00}(\mathbb{R})$ such that  $\|f-g_n\|_1\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.
Then, by translation invariance
\begin{align}
\Big|\|g_n(\cdot+ t)-g_n(\cdot)\|_1-\|f(\cdot +t) - f(\cdot)\|\Big|&\leq
\|f(\cdot+t)-g_n(\cdot+t)-f(\cdot)+g_n(\cdot+t)\|_1\\
&\leq2\|f-g_n\|_1\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0
\end{align}

Notice that
\begin{align}
\big|2\|f\|_1-\|f(\cdot+t)-f(\cdot)\|\big|&\leq2\big|\|f\|_1-\|g_n\|_1\big|+\big|2\|g_n\|_1-\|g_n(\cdot+t)-g_n(\cdot)\|_1\big|+\\
&\qquad \big|\|g_n(\cdot+t)-g_n(\cdot)\|_1-\|f(\cdot+t)-f(\cdot)\|_1\big|\\
&\leq 4\|f-g_n\|_1+\big|2\|g_n\|_1-\|g_n(\cdot+t)-g_n(\cdot)\|_1\big|
\end{align}

Fix $n$ large enough so that $4\|f-g_n\|_1<\varepsilon$. Then choose $T>0$ large enough so that for $t>T$, $\operatorname{supp}{g_n}\cap(\operatorname{supp}{g_n}-t)=\emptyset$ which yields
$\big|2\|g_n\|_1-\|g_n(\cdot+t)-g_n(\cdot)\|_1\big|=0$.
Putting things together, we obtain  that for $t>T$
\begin{align}
\big|2\|f\|_1-\|f(\cdot+t)-f(\cdot)\|\big|<\varepsilon
\end{align}
Therefore
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\|f(\cdot +t)-f(\cdot)\|_1=2\|f\|_1$$

Comment: thanks a lot! I understand my mistake and shall delete my answer.